# xcode storyboard: Having visual problems with navigation controllers

Tags: ios, xcode

This is a cut out of my storyboard:
[image]

I can see the navigation bars on all views (shown on picture) when I build and run my app.

Now I added a new ViewController to my structure (that one with the red bordered question box) and I am not able to add a navigation item button because I can't see the navigation bar.

And I am also not able to add a navigation bar button the the view with the 4 orange buttons. I can see there the navigation bar, but I can't drag and drop a navigation item to it.

Something is really mixed up in my (first) app project.
Can someone please explain what I have to do to setup all views right?

I double checked, all controllers have these settings:

If needed I can also update my post and show my document outline settings for each controller?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Storyboard seems correct, if when you run the app the navigation bar is there, then it is definitely something from the simulated metrics for that particular ViewController. Try to switch to other Top Bar settings and see if it changes in the Storyboard (for the view controller with label1 label2).

Comment: If I set the Top Bar to `Translucent Navigation Bar`, I can see the navigation bar, but still can not add a Bar Button Item

Comment: I guess you are trying to drag and drop the barButtonItem. You are pushing that viewController, so I don't think the navBar is broken. Just in case, try to delete the segue for that one, and redo it, maybe it's just a small trick/error.

Comment: what I tried now was to hold `alt` key pressed and dragged the bar button into the document outline of the View. Maybe not a clean way, but it helped and the app is working fine so far.

Comment: Happy it worked, even if don't see any role of the alt key, never used it for droping UI components.